# Summarize by group the maximum amount of time a range of values continuously occurred in R

Tags: r, summarization

Say I have a dataframe that ***looks*** like this (wasn't sure how to actually rep. this data, given its size):

```
minutes <- seq(0,585, by = 15)
salinity <-  as.numeric(sample(x = 29:55, size  = 40, replace = TRUE))
site <- c(1, 2, 3, ...etc.)
year <- c(2020, 2019, ...etc.)
season <- c("Dry", "Wet")

df <- cbind.data.frame(year, season, site, minutes, salinity)

> head(df)
  year season site minutes salinity
1 2020    DRY    1       0       54
2 2020    DRY    1      15       39
3 2020    DRY    1      30       44
4 2020    DRY    1      45       54
5 2020    DRY    1      60       43
6 2020    DRY    1      75       40
```

and in reality it has +800k rows of continuously measured data in 15 min. increments for the past couple of years at "n" sites.

I'm attempting to make a matrix/table like this in R (that was originally created in Excel). Color is not important, I only hope to re-create the table itself. The values in this plot are the maximum/highest number of minutes where a range of values were consistently measured (ex. For each site, season, and year,  create a table that shows the longest lasting run of continuous minutes where the values stayed between 40-50).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

one approach, using an example dataframe **df** of two sites:

```
df <- dput(df)
structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), year = c(2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L), season = c("DRY", "DRY", "DRY", "DRY", "DRY", "DRY", "DRY", "DRY", "DRY", "DRY"), site = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), minutes = c(0L, 15L, 30L, 45L, 60L, 0L, 15L, 30L, 45L, 60L), salinity = c(1L, 1L, 40L, 40L, 1L, 1L, 45L, 40L, 40L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
10L))
```

code:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(site, season, year) %>%
  mutate(high_salinity = between(salinity, 40, 50),
         high_salinity_duration  = cumsum(high_salinity) *
           high_salinity
         ) %>%
  summarise(longest_high_salinity = max(high_salinity_duration))
```

output:

```
## # A tibble: 2 x 4
## # Groups:   site, season [2]
##    site season  year longest_high_salinity
##   <int> <chr>  <int>                 <int>
## 1     1 DRY     2020                     2
## 2     2 DRY     2020                     3
```

Comment: Thank you. Do I need to add anything to this code to make sure its only considering consecutive salinity values to be consecutive by the time column without any 
breaks (ex. 0015 -> 0030 -> 0045, without breaks)?

Comment: Maybe I need to make a single time variable instead of splitting it up by several columns (not year, month, day, time, but all those in 1 column)?

Comment: While this shouldn't be a technical problem (code), it would also break up longer saline periods where e. g. instrument failure caused a small gap in measurements. If you want to avoid this, it'd be better to impute missing data (for small periods) e.g. by moving average.

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial answer, but I keep getting an error:

```
result = df %>% mutate(tim = str_pad(time, 4, side = "left", pad = "0"),
                       hour = substring(time, 1, 2),
                       minute = substring(time, 3, 4),
                       stamp = make_datetime(yr, mo, day, hour, minute),
                       high_salinity = between(sal, range.min, range.max)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(stamp), !is.na(high_salinity)) %>%
  arrange(yr, seas, wq., stamp) %>%
  group_by(yr, seas, wq.) %>%
  mutate(days = ifelse(row_number() != n(), - as.numeric(stamp - lead(stamp), units = "days"), 0),
         shift = ifelse(high_salinity == lag(high_salinity) | row_number() == 1, 0, 1) %>% cumsum) %>%
  group_by(yr, seas, wq., shift) %>%
  mutate(time_high = cumsum(days * high_salinity)) %>%
  group_by(yr, seas, wq.) %>%
  summarise(max_high = max(time_high)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = yr, values_from = max_high)

    Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `stamp`.
    i `stamp = make_datetime(yr, mo, day, hour, minute)`.
    x Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=integer].
```

#######################################################################

UPDATE:

As the error implies, the make_datetime function only accepts numeric values from "hour" and "minute" objects. These need to be converted first from POSIX to character, then convert hour and minute objects to numeric. The code will run from there.

```
range.min = 40
range.max = 50

z <- df$mo
df$seas <- ifelse(z<= 10 & z >= 5, "wet", "dry")

# Convert R time to military character string
df$miltime <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$time) , " ") , function(x) {
  s <- x[[2]]
  s <- strsplit(s , ":")
  sapply(s , function(x) paste0(x[1],x[2]))
}) 

df <- df %>% mutate(time = str_pad(miltime, 4, side = "left", pad = "0"),
                    hour = substring(miltime, 1, 2),
                    minute = substring(miltime, 3, 4))

df$hour <- as.numeric(df$hour)
df$minute <- as.numeric(df$minute)


result = df %>% mutate(stamp = make_datetime(yr, mo, day, hour, minute),
                       high_salinity = between(sal, range.min, range.max)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(stamp), !is.na(high_salinity)) %>%
  arrange(yr, mo, day, `wq#`, stamp) %>%
  group_by(yr, mo, day, `wq#`) %>%
  mutate(days = ifelse(row_number() != n(), - as.numeric(stamp - lead(stamp), units = "days"), 0),
         shift = ifelse(high_salinity == lag(high_salinity) | row_number() == 1, 0, 1) %>% cumsum) %>%
  group_by(yr, mo, day, `wq#`, shift) %>%
  mutate(time_high = cumsum(days * high_salinity)) %>%
  group_by(yr, mo, day, `wq#`) %>%
  summarise(max_high = max(time_high)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = yr, values_from = max_high)
```